# Fundamental group of this quotient of the disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, quotient-spaces

This is an exercise from Bredon:

> Let $X$ be the quotient space of $\mathbb{D}^2$ obtained by identifying points on the boundary that are 120º apart. Find $\pi_1(X)$.

Could you give me any hints on how to proceed?

I tried to apply Van-Kampen's theorem to the sets $U = B(0,1/2)$ and $V = X \setminus \{0\}$, but what is the fundamental group of $V$?

Comment: $\pi_1V =\langle a,b|a^3=b \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the above picture, Here the red, blue and purple arcs are identified.

You have $\Pi_{1}(U)=\{0\}$ and $\Pi_{1}(V)=\langle a\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z} $ where $a$ denotes the path $t\mapsto e^{2i\pi t}$ .

And $U\cap V$ deformation retracts to the path $a^{3}$ . $\Pi_{1}(U\cap V)=\langle a^{3}\rangle \cong \Bbb{Z}$ .

Thus By Van-Kampen Theorem, $\Pi_{1}(X)$ is the amalgamated product over $\Pi_{1}(U\cap V)$ . So $\Pi_{1}(X)= \langle a : a^{3}= 1\rangle = \frac{\Bbb{Z}}{\Bbb{3Z}}$

Answer (score 0):

Three points in $\partial D^2 =S^1$ are same. Hence quotient space
$\partial D^2/\sim$ is still $S^1$. Hence $\pi_1(
\partial D^2/\sim )=\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}=(a)$.

But in $X$, curve representing $a^3$ is contractible. Hence
$\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: What theorems are you using here? Intuitively I understand your point, but could you be more rigorous?